# When drag and drop a button from button to button, the button is down

Tags: python, pyside2

The button is down after drag and drop.

Is there any way to return to the original state automatically after dropping it?

And I want to avoid subclassing the buttons if possible.

Currently, I'm testing on events other than drop.

The image of the button below and the code being tested.

[image]

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from functools import partial

class DragTest(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super(DragTest, self).__init__()

        cent = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(cent)

        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(cent)
        self.color1_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(acceptDrops=True)
        self.color1_btn.clicked.connect(partial(self.color_btn_click, widget=self.color1_btn))
        self.color2_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(acceptDrops=True)
        self.color2_btn.clicked.connect(partial(self.color_btn_click, widget=self.color2_btn))
        layout.addWidget(self.color1_btn)
        layout.addWidget(self.color2_btn)
        self.color1_btn.installEventFilter(self)
        self.color2_btn.installEventFilter(self)
        self.color1_btn.color = self.color2_btn.color = None

        self.btn1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        self.btn2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        layout.addWidget(self.btn1)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn2)

    def color_btn_click(self, widget):
        color = QtWidgets.QColorDialog.getColor()
        if color.isValid():
            self.set_color(widget, color)

    def set_color(self, widget, color):
        widget.setStyleSheet("background-color:rgb({0},{1},{2})".format(*color.getRgb()))
        widget.color = color
    
    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if obj in {self.color1_btn, self.color2_btn}:
            if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseMove and obj.color:
                mimedata = QtCore.QMimeData()
                mimedata.setColorData(obj.color)
                
                pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(20, 20)
                pixmap.fill(QtCore.Qt.transparent)
                painter = QtGui.QPainter(pixmap)
                painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
                painter.setBrush(obj.color)
                painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(obj.color.darker(150), 2))
                painter.drawEllipse(pixmap.rect().center(), 8, 8)
                painter.end()
                
                drag = QtGui.QDrag(obj)
                drag.setMimeData(mimedata)
                drag.setPixmap(pixmap)
                drag.setHotSpot(pixmap.rect().center())
                drag.exec_(QtCore.Qt.CopyAction)
                
            elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.DragEnter:
                event.accept() if event.mimeData().hasColor() else event.ignore()

            elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Drop:
                self.set_color(obj, event.mimeData().colorData())
                self.color1_btn.setDown(False)
                self.color2_btn.setDown(False)
                event.accept()
                
        return super(DragTest, self).eventFilter(obj, event)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = DragTest()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

1. downed button restore
2. if possible avoid pushbutton subclassing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that after the `drag.exec_()` (which is *blocking*), the mouse move event is still going to be processed by the event filter as soon as the drag event loop is completed, which means that the event will be sent to the button *after* the drag.

At that point the mouse button has already been released, but the button didn't receive it because the mouseButtonRelease event has been "eaten" by the drag release action, which is *then* followed by the mouseMove event that was blocked before.

To the point of view of the button, you have pressed the mouse button, but you didn't release it: what it received was just the last mouse move event (the one used for the drag creation), so it "believes" that the mouse is still on it, with the button pressed.

Whenever an event has been *managed* and should not be processed further, the filter should return `True`:

```py
    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if obj in {self.color1_btn, self.color2_btn}:
            if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseMove and obj.color:
                # ...
                drag.exec_(QtCore.Qt.CopyAction)
                obj.setDown(False)
                return True

            elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.DragEnter:
                event.accept() if event.mimeData().hasColor() else event.ignore()

            elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Drop:
                self.set_color(obj, event.mimeData().colorData())
                # self.color1_btn.setDown(False)
                # self.color2_btn.setDown(False)
                event.accept()
```

Comment: It's a little hard, but I think I'll know when I test it! Thank you.

Comment: @chowooseoung just think about the whole event "timeline": there is a MouseButtonPressed, which is processed by the button, then there's a MouseMove which is *filtered* and then *blocked* by the `drag.exec_()` (remember, all `exec_()` functions in Qt are **blocking**), then all subsequent events are drag events (move and drop), once the dropEvent is completed, `drag.exec_()` *returns*, which means that only *then* the MouseMove event will be actually processed by the rest of the eventFilter implementation: to the point of view of the button, nothing "mouse-wise" has happened in the meantime.